# Raspberry Pi 3b+ loses WIFI connection after 10 minutes

Tags: wifi, connection

My Raspberry Pi 3b+ loses WIFI connection after 10 minutes, after it loses connection, I cant re-connect because there are no WIFI networks in the dropdown list. My only option was to completely restart the raspberry pi every 10 minutes or so. There has got to be a better approach than just restarting the raspberry pi to restore the internet connection.

Comment: What power supply are you using?  I chased many WiFi issues on the 3B+ till I moved to the official supply and they went away.

Comment: @Andrew, I am using a 5v 3A power adapter. And I have a 7" LCD screen connected to it, so it needs the full 3A).

Comment: Add `iwconfig wlan0 power off` to `/etc/rc.local` to get that run at every boot up.

Comment: @Dougie - odd I thought that was not needed any more.  Saying that none of my Pis at home are running that command but all stay connected fine and have a mix of power management on and off as reported by `sudo iwconfig wlan0` - one day I may understand a little more than I do now :-)

Comment: @Andrew the RPF/RPTL folks have been asked to change the default. They won't. power saving isn't useful on a [hopefully] always connected server system. Setting power off stops the WiFi from sleeping. That's set on every one of my fifteen raspberries. My unexpected disconnections stopped completely when I upgraded the TP-Link firmware in my router/access point.